# Unable to access public url from Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, web-services, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to access a public url from the Google Cloud Platform. But each time, I am getting connection timeout error. That URL is very well opening in my browsers and on different network as well. I am using Python to make a `POST` request to this URL and locally it is working fine. I don't know if need to set some security measures in Google or not.

Thanks and regards
Vipendra Singh Sengar

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Can you share the URL with us? There shouldn't be anything preventing you from making requests to external URLs.

Comment: You should specify the cloud product are you using and how (if GAE - what environment and python version), show the code attempting to make the request and the errors that you get. The question is way too broad at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned here [How to access websites that have ip block on GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67713323/how-to-access-websites-that-have-ip-block-on-gcp-services-using-cloud-run-or-clo)

*By default, a Cloud Run service connects to external endpoints on the internet using a dynamic IP address pool.Which is problematic if you want to access an external website that requires connections originating from a static IP address, such as a database or API using an IP address-based firewall.*

So you need to get an [Static outbound IP address](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip)