# How to access websites that have ip block on GCP services using Cloud Run or Cloud Funcions

Tags: web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run, ip-blocking

I'm trying to access a site using Google Cloud Functions or Cloud Run.

But it looks like it's blocking the IPs coming from these services

Locally the code works fine. I've tried to add a lot of headers to simulate a local call, but it doesn't work.

Some of the headers:

```
--header 'Connection: keep-alive' 
--header 'Accept: /' 
--header 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' 
--header 'Origin: <site fororigin>'
--header 'Referer: <site for referer>'
--header 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' 
--header 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' 
--header 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' 
--header 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty'
--header 'Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
```

It also works if I create a VM on my region (south america) but this solution will create a lot of automation complexities

Is there a way to work around the Ip block? maybe by calling another server to change the IP?

Comment: Only if you know which IP addresses, they are blocking can you develop a strategy to use a different IP address. If the other side does not want Google IP addresses hitting their servers, then use a different cloud or provider. Most likely they do not want "YOUR" traffic and have blocked you. Changing IP addresses will be a short-term solution in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the documentation on this topic which explains how to get a static IP address, which you can ask to be whitelisted, and use it for outbound connections on Cloud Run.  https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip

This involves routing your external traffic through a VPC Connector to a VPC that has NAT configuration with one or more static IP addresses. That way, Cloud Run will be using those IPs when it connects to external endpoints.

Comment: Not sure exactly what each components do, but it works nicely! Unfortunable because of the new IP, I had to acess some cloud SQL databases using an external ip instead of the instance name. I will take some time to explore a little more those components do. Thanks a lot!